# High Available Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, azure-aks

We are starting migrating our system from Azure web app services to AKS infrastructure and currently we had an incident with our test cluster and connection to all our environments were lost. It was due to the upgrading version of Kubernetes and adding additional node pool which broke the route table and they lost communication between themselves.

So as a result we came up with the next HA infrastructure for our environments:

[image: Infra for HA AKS]

But that eventually adds more work on the CI/CD pipelines and doesn't look very logically as Kubernetes itself should be reliable.

Can I have your comments and thoughts if it is best practice or proper way of moving forward?

Comment: How many your web app pods? I didn't see it(upgrading version of Kubernetes and adding additional node pool) broken in GKE. Are you also deploy database in AKS?

Comment: No DBs or any data storages, we'll have around 25 pods.